# Changing angular 6 Row Colour according to condition

Tags: javascript, angular6

I am currently  working with angular 6 and I have to make
lines of a table change according to the content of the row.

So i am using  conditional statement with `ngif`. I am wondering if there is a way to do that without making 2 Ngif statements?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: You want us to help you change your code. It would be helpful if you would show us your code then ...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need angular or javascript - just CSS - the following uses the `:nth-of-type(even)` selector.

Only the tr's that satisfy your ngIf condition will show and this stylning will be applied to every second row irrespective of the number of rows that don't show.

```css
table {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

tr:nth-of-type(even) {
background: yellow; 
color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>David</td>
    <td>Griffith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do it with ngStyle:

```
[ngStyle]
  <li  [ngStyle]= "{ 'backgroundColor' : (film.duree=='2 heures') ? 'blue' : 'red'  }">  {{ film.nom}}-   {{ film.duree}}-  {{ film.categorie}}</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to directly marking a style, provided a predicate you can easily switch a class that contains your style information using Angular property binding:

```
<li [class.my-class]="condition">data</li>
```